# Подскажите пожалуйста с чем может быть связана ошибка при пересылке данных?

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, g++, сокеты

Разрабатываю клиент серверное приложение и в нем возникает ошибка при пересылке данных. Заключается она в следующем:

Я пересылаю данные с клиента на сервер. С клиента отправляю 32, а на сервер приходит 323 или с любым другим случайным хвостом. Ошибка возникает не всегда, ниже выложил код отправки сообщения на сервер.

```
int get_msg(int sock,char *Text)
{
      int k=1024;
       char buf[k];

    int bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, k, 0);
        if(bytes_read <= 0){return 1;}
        Text=strcpy(Text,buf);
        k-=bytes_read;
        while(k!=0)
        {

            bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, k, 0);
             if(bytes_read <= 0){return 1;}
             Text=strcat(Text,buf);
             k-=bytes_read;
        }
    cout<<"\nGET="<<Text<<" GET_bytes="<<bytes_read<<endl;
    return 0;
}
int send_msg(int sock,char *Text)
{
    /**/
    int k=1024;
    int bytes_send = send(sock, Text, k, 0);

        if(bytes_send <= 0) {return 1;}
         cout<<"\nSEND="<<Text<<" SEND_bytes="<<bytes_send<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Приложения построены на сокетах,сокеты корректно запускаются и работают, На вход так же подается нормальное сообщение.

Comment: а как клиент узнает, сколько символов нужно прочитать? он читает сколько получиться. И Вы читаете текущую посылку и кусок следующей.

Comment: Как же 32, если написано голубым по белому 1024?

Comment: 1024 это количество байт, которое посылается. На вход в переменную Text заносится текст, и отсылается.

Comment: @boikov 

Пока я вижу такую ситуацию.

Командой send вы отправляете 1024 байта.
Так как в char *Text находится только 32 байта то остальные 992 байта это случайный мусор, в которых может быть 0.

Командой recv вы принимаете 1024 байта.
Далее в 'Text' заносятся 32 байта + количество байт до символа 0, но не более 1024.

Надо:

send(sock, Text, РАЗМЕР_text, 0);
Размер у вас должен передаваться вместе с char *Text.
Если char *Text точно оканчивается нулем, то можно использовать strlen(Text)

Вот так вот:
send(sock, Text, strlen(Text), 0);

Comment: @boikov, вот код

    Text=strcpy(Text,buf)

и

    Text=strcat(Text,buf)

это неправильно.

По крайней мере (если у Вас двоичные нули точно не передаются)

    buf[bytes_read] = 0;

надо перед strcpy() и strcat() добавить, и размер буфера в таком случае (передаете-то 1024 байта) на 1 увеличьте.

--

А в Вашем случае (k уменьшается от 1024 до 0) проще так: 

    int end = 0;
    ...
    while (k) {
      n = recv(s, &text[end], k, 0);
      ....
      k -= n; end += n;
    }

--

Вообще, при отладке подобных кусочков печатайте, сколько байт вернул recv() и полученные данные в 16-ричном виде.

Comment: @boikov, и еще

    С клиента отправляю 32, а на сервер приходит 323 или с любым другим случайным хвостом.

это я, например, не понял. 

Вы 32 байта (какое содержимое?) хотите отправить или текст "32"? Тогда зачем в send (...,1024,..)???

Ну и т.д. Описывайте поточнее свои *намерения*, ведь их не всегда можно из Вашего кода извлечь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл принятия данных из сокета

`int temp = 0, revved = 0, size = 1024; 
do {
 . temp = recv(sock, str + revved, size - revved, 0); 
 . if(temp > 0)
.    . revved += temp; 
   else break;
while(revved < size); 
printf("%s", str);`

Comment: Алгоритм send такой же